# IE,FF try{}catch(){} bug?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I defined function name as _ , defined function fn

```
function _(){};

function fn(){ 
    try{
       console.info(_);
    }catch(_){
       //
    } 
    return _;
}

fn();
```

in FF output _(), but IE8 output undefined, why this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**  @kevinpeng thanks to updating to question original version

ie7 does not support window.console   (I can't test as i don't have it)
ie8 supports it console if you open developer tools by F12

in firefox you can use, no problem.

so not to have error in your code:

You can do this, for console.log:

```
function myConsole(param) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, and any other browser that follows ES3/ES5, the return value should be the function object you call "_".

In IE8, however, it hoists any catch-statement variable bindings to the top of the function. e.g.,

```
function fn() {
  try {
    return foo;
  }
  catch(foo) {}
}
```

effectively does

```
function fn() {
  var foo;
  try {
    return foo;
  }
  catch(foo) {}
}
```

Note this is the same var statements (they are created and set to undefined at the start of the function, and assigned a specific value when execution reaches the var statement).